# Postgres, pgadmin,

Tags: postgresql, timeout, setting

My query cannot run longer than 15minutes. (Putting query efficiency aside)

I have tried imitating Postgres settings from another workstation that is able to complete this query at 16mins. The settings that I have tried are tcp_keepalive and maintenance_work_mem.

Has anyone any idea to solve this?

it stays at 15minutes no matter how long I waited.
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Put some code

Comment: No matter what query, if it takes more than 15minutes, the query editor will keep waiting and the timer stays at 15th minutes with no result shown.

What I have done is changing these settings,

tcp_keepalives_count=0
tcp_keepalives_idle=7200
tcp_keepalives_interval=75
work mem = 4096

Comment: You are probably looking for `statement_timeout`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT

Comment: Please clarify: Does your query stop after 15 minutes? Do you want it to stop after 15 minutes? Or is your problem not the query, but that the time displayed in pgAdmin does not go beyond 15 minutes? What version of pgAdmin is it?

Comment: What is the result of `select pg_sleep(16*60);`?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: statement_timeout is set to 0. I never modify that.

Laurenz Albe: My problem is not the query, my problem is not able to get the results if a query took longer than 15minutes. If a query takes 14minutes, it is fine.

Abelisto: Running, 10:15minutes has passed. will let you know when it is done.

Comment: select pg_sleep(16*60); unable to run. It stops at 15th minutes.

A pop up occur, saying connection to database lost. Do you want to attempt to reconnect to the database? Yes No.

Comment: anyone know what went wrong?